# How to describe a person who is non-aggresive and not good at pushing other people?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

I'm writing an article to describe a person who is not aggresive and not good at pushing other people during work collaboration. But I can't figure our what word or phrase is suitable for it. Can you please help me?

By "pushing other people" I mean, e.g. if someone doesn't try his best in a project but you have to depend on him to complete your work, aggresive people may push him hard to get his work done in a timely manner, even if there might be a fierece quarrel. But I'm trying a person who is opposite to such aggresive one.

Thanks!

Comment: Do non aggressive and respectful people exist?

Comment: You mean someone who's too afraid to be openly aggressive (shy, unassertive, etc); or someone who's laid back and doesn't get upset or rushed; or someone who's otherwise well-balanced but not good at motivating people?

Comment: You are supposed to include an example sentence where you want a single word suggestion.